# Image picker from gallery similar to WhatsApp and contacts profile pic picker [Blackberry]

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my app I want the user to be able to open a file picker same as the one in WhatsApp and Contacts to choose a profile picture.

Can anyone guide me on how to implement this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

For OS 6.0 and later, it is pretty straightforward. Use the [FilePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/FilePicker.html):

```
FilePicker picker = FilePicker.getInstance();
picker.setView(FilePicker.VIEW_PICTURES);
picker.show();
```

Comment: Perhaps you can take my answer, and use it to figure out an answer that works for you on OS 5.0.